# How Do I Change The Colour Of The Apple Icon In The Menu Bar

Tags: icon, menu-bar

The apple icon in the menu bar is a black gradient (everything on this MacBook Pro seems to be a shade of grey!).

How can I change the icon to use the classic fruit colours instead?

Comment: Something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8wqOkrlX5Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a youtube video that covers how to do this in Mountain Lion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8wqOkrlX5Q

It appears to be the same in mavericks.  The easier way to get to the folders in Finder is click Go > Go to Folder, or hit Shift-Command-G and in the window type `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources` and the other folder is `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

The files in Mavericks seemed to be named `apple_s1.png`, `apple_s1@2x.png`, `apple.png` and `apple@2x.png`.

Good luck

Comment: There are some additional challenges in actually editing these files to change the color.

Comment: Actually, the only part I need to change the Apple Icon in the Menu Bar is to install http://www.sigsoftware.com/classicmenu/ then in the preferences select "Show system Apple menu when: -> Mouse within: - Inside"

Comment: Yeah, there is usually some software out there that does what you want, but sometimes it's fun to get your hands dirty in the system files, lol.

Comment: And ClassicMenu doesn't work in macOS 10.7 or later (nor 10.6 on Intel CPUs); it's PowerPC-only.

PS: The corresponding files I'm seeing in macOS 10.13 are: apple_s4.png, apple_s4@2x.png, apple.png, and apple@2x.png.